# Screen Compatibility

Tags: android, android-screen, android-screen-support

I have developed an Application for android compatible devices mostly covered mobile phones, but when I am running it on Tab the screen size will get changed and all the content on the particular screen not behaving properly, As I have designed it keeping in mind that it should be compatible  with mobile phones

Now, I just wanted to run my app on tab with the same screen size as it is showing on my mobile phone, without stretching of screen size.

What should I do to achieve it ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a question that can be answered with a simple "set this style flag on your activity and you'll be on your way!" kind of answer.  To get an app to scale properly across multiple screen sizes, you really need to start with the layout design itself.  Android will try to keep your components the same size across different screen densities, but if you just leave it at that it still won't look very good because you'll have lots of empty or poorly utilized space.

The platform documentation and design guidelines go fairly in-depth into screen size compatibility and making a single app work and look good across all screens, large and small.  In particular, I recommend reading the following articles:

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
[Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)
[Supporting Different Screen Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

It'll take some work to make your app look and work great on tablets and phones (with just one APK) but if you want to make a good experience on a tablet without the hassle of maintaining two separate codebases, it's worth learning.

Pay particular attention to [size qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSizeQuali), which allow you to load different resources (drawables, layouts, etc) based on screen size (small, medium, large, x-large).  That way you don't have to just blindly scale everything up on a tablet... if appropriate, you can tweak your layout on a tablet to make the experience more user-friendly.

Additionally, I recommend looking into [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), which allow for lots of flexibility in your UI across tablets and phones while not requiring you to have to write a bunch of code for differing layouts. For example, instead of having a newsreader that has two screens, one to display a list of articles and one to display article content, you can use Fragments to have a side-by-side, two-pane view of articles and content on tablets, while still having two separate screens on phones, which are more narrow.  Fragments and FragmentActivities make this much easier to write and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You could set layouts width and height in pixels.

It probably isn't the only way but it's what comes to my mind right now.